# How to re-launch (unrevoke) a revoked task with Celery?

Tags: python, celery

Is there any way to **"unrevoke" tasks using Celery**? I need to be able to manually re-launch previously revoked tasks. If it isn't directly possible, is there a way to copy the revoked task and launch a new one with exactly the same parameters?

Here is a little example:

```
app = Celery('tests', broker='redis://localhost:6379/0')
app.conf.update(
    CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'redis://localhost:6379/0',
    CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER='json',
    CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT=['json'],
    CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER='json',
)

@app.task
def add(x, y):
    return x + y

task = add.delay(1, 2)
task.revoke(terminate=True)

# ...
# Something happens here and now I need to actually launch the revoked task.
# I'd need something like...
task.restart()  # How can I do this?
```

Comment: I believe task.retry() may work for you.

Comment: @user2097159 `retry()` is used to relaunch the task after an exception, but in my case I need to be able to relaunch it manually after a `revoke()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `delay` returns an `AsyncResult` instance, which do not know how your task was launched.

You could try keeping the signature of the task, and relaunch it.

```
sig = add.s(1, 2)
task = sig.apply_async()
task.revoke(terminate=True)

# ...

task  = sig.apply_async()  # Will relaunch a task with the same parameters.
```

Comment: After further reading the docs, I found that the `Signature` objects would be the best option... Your example is perfect and works well! Just one more question... Is there any general approach to persist the signature objects using Python in an easy way (shelve maybe)? Stored in a dict fashion would be perfect to retrieve the signatures by task id. Thanks!

Comment: Signature object is a subclass of dict, so, yes, you can serialize it just by casting it as a dict, and thus persist it in any form you want (memory, database). You can unserialize it by calling `Signature.from_dict` classmethod.